# Spring Boot Test MockMvc get custom header value

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I am using Spring Boot v2.4.2. I have set up Spring Security and Session Management, so it returns "x-auth-token" in the response headers. I tested this with Postman and browser. It has this header, which is perfect.
Then inside my Springboot integration tests, I tried to read this header in the reponse. But it doesn't have this header. I receive all the other header, except this. I guess it is because of a custom header. Any idea? here is my code.

```
MockHttpServletResponse response =
            mockMvc.perform(post("/api/user-management/auth/login").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myDataObject)))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())                        
                    .andReturn().getResponse();
    System.out.println("Token: " + response.getHeaderValue("x-auth-token"));
```

I have set up set up mockMvc as follows.

```
@BeforeEach
public void setUp(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext, RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation) {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).apply(springSecurity())         
                   .build();
}
```

Comment: Where do you populate the `x-auth-token` header value? As part of your controller/security config/filter?

Comment: in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionStrategy() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
    }